# Detecting Apache worker delays in PHP

Tags: php, apache, lamp

We have a series of Apache servers that are getting overwhelmed and keeping requests queued for a while before they are serviced.

While we tune that, we realized our PHP logs didn't have visibility into how long that delay was... is there an env variable put out by apache for each thread, or a php function that can tell how long the request took, not from the initialization of PHP, but when Apache first opened the connection?

Comment: you will be loooking for something server based like nagios.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in PHP available to my knowledge. It might not even be possible for Apache to provide this information depending on the way your server was overwhelmed:

If Apache ran out of workers, the client would simply sit and wait for the TCP connection to be established. Apache would not know that another client is waiting, as all workers are currently busy serving other clients.

PHP is the last component that gets to know the client request, so dealing with the problem there, or at least trying to find out a request was significantly delayed is not possible with only server data.

You might be able to add a client-side timestamp into the request - however, client's clocks need not be in sync with the server clock, and syncing them would be a problem if the server already has a delay. Adding more requests to report the problem will also increase the load on the server.